# how to Pass query string in 404 error redirect through .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an `index.php` file which handles all requests to the server. I've set up a 404 error redirect in `.htaccess` in this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

If a users request a file, say, `page.php`, then it gets redirected to the `index.php` page properly.

The problem arises when the users request `page.php?page=about, then my index.php is unable to retrieve the query`about`using`$_REQUEST['page']`.

How can i get the query `about` through the index.php using `$_REQUEST['page']` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']` may contain your query strings.

Give this a shot.

```
<?php
    print_r($_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']);
?>
```

Comment: can i put $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'] into $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ?

Comment: thnaks, i can modify $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] :) thnaks a lot :)

Comment: See as well [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str).