# Why is my QUERY_STRING empty?

Tags: php, apache2, query-string, http-status-code-404

I am running a server locally. It's Apache2 with PHP. Following are the files that I have written.

`.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notFoundError.php
```

`/notFoundError.php`

```
<?php
  echo phpinfo();
?>
```

When I type some non-existing url `http://localhost/this/is/dummy?key=value`, it successfully redirects to `notFoundError.php` and prints the phpinfo table. There I do not find `key=value` in the `_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` row.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_SERVER)`, maybe it's in there somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Pass query string in 404 error redirect through .haccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366139/how-to-pass-query-string-in-404-error-redirect-through-haccess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [how to Pass query string in 404 error redirect through .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366139/how-to-pass-query-string-in-404-error-redirect-through-haccess) for your answer.

> You will need to access $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending to a page which does not exist, a 404 will be invoked.
Which is why you are being redirect to notFoundError.php and then displaying its contents?

What are you trying to accomplish?