# PHP 'QUERY_STRING' not returning anything

Tags: php, string

I'm using the following in my php code:

```
$file="query.txt";
$f=fopen($file,'a');
fwrite($f,"Query String:".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."\n");
fclose($f);
```

It never returns anything. I'm simply trying to record the queried url when someone visits (i.e. http://example.com/index.php?q=string. Other $_SERVER fields seem to work just fine, it only seems to be the query string that doesn't work. Maybe there's something I need to setup in my .htaccess?

I'm hoping someone has an answer to how to get this to information to show.

Comment: replace `$_SERVER` with `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`

Comment: Try looking at the result of `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SERVER, true) . '</pre>';` and verify that `QUERY_STRING` is there.

Comment: @alfasin, tried both - still no results.

Comment: @Supericy, that does return the query_string. so the question is why does my code above not? thanks

Comment: yep, it exists and writes other .$_SERVER information in there just fine.

Comment: what's the output of `echo $_GET['q'];` ?

Comment: why not just do a var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]); at the begining of your code file

Comment: I got the feeling that Ned is banging his head against the keyboard right now... the HTTP parameter name is `q` not `QUERY_STRING`... :)))

Comment: This solved it `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']` -- thanks for your help everyone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']
```

solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11618256/1125006